# Install package that is not on stackage but on hackage

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hackage, stackage

I'm trying to use a library that's on hackage, but not on stackage.

Currently, the code doesn't seem to be hosted on git anywhere (although I could "fork" it).

Are there any better ways than to just download the library locally and tell `stack.yaml` where to find it?

The library is [parse-dimacs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parse-dimacs-1.3) by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stack` allows you to specify dependencies that are not included in the (Stackage) snapshot as [`extra-deps`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#extra-deps) in your `stack.yaml`.

To use `parse-dimacs` in your project, you'd add this stanza to your `stack.yaml`:

```yaml
extra-deps:
- parse-dimacs-1.3
```